# Is the expression "I'm wearing shorts and sandals in the morning" correct?

Tags: verbs, present-continuous, tense-agreement

The time expression "In the morning" can imply a different moment, not necessarily something which is happning at the moment of speaking.
idea

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is no mistake with "I'm wearing shorts and sandals in the morning"  What is your **actual communication problem**?

Answer (score 0):

**in the morning** can mean "tomorrow morning".

> It's late, and I want to go to bed. Can I call you back in the morning?

And it can refer to the time of day generally:

> She waters her garden in the morning.

Her general practice is to water her garden early in the day.

Comment: Correct. But the time of day can **also be expressed** as a plural e.g "I spend mornings in the garden and afternoons reading".

Comment: And Saturdays you can go  to the supermarket. It's a vestige of an oblique case ending, like the German form.

Comment: The question was "is it ok to use the present progressive with in the morning. You didn't answer it...

Comment: @Lambie The body of the question reads: "The time expression 'In the morning' can imply a different moment, not necessarily something which is happning at the moment of speaking."  There's nothing there about the present progressive. Maybe you're right, but it's hardly clear enough for you to be telling me that I didn't answer the question.

Comment: @TimR Well said! But on the matter of the present progressive - yes it is alright. However the present progressive can, idiomatically, be used widely in a future context - e.g. "Next year I am going to France on holiday, and I am taking the children with me"

Comment: Of course, the OP didn't know about the present progressive and only mentions in the morning. However, you didn't answer the question which can only be about: present simple versus present progressive + in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

I wear sandals and shorts in the morning. [a generality]

I'm wearing sandals and shorts in the morning. [tomorrow, progressive used as a future]

I go to bed early. [generally]

I'm going to bed early. [tonight]

> T**he Present Progressive Tense for Future Events In English, we often
> use the present progressive (be + verb + ing) to talk about future
> events which have already been planned.** **Time words in the sentence,
> such as next week, next year, tomorrow, etc., make it clear that the
> action is not happening at this moment.**
>
> Be careful. Verbs that describe states rather than actions are not
> used in the progressive form. These include words like know, believe,
> hear, love seem own and need. Study the examples below.
>
> I'm playing golf with some friends on Saturday. (correct)

[University of Victoria, present progressive for a future event](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-expressing-the-future/#:%7E:text=The%20Present%20Progressive%20Tense%20for,not%20happening%20at%20this%20moment.)